# Finding DKIM selectors without mailing

Tags: email, dkim

Is there any way to find out what selectors are used by a domain in their DKIM record without access to an e-mail send from that domain?

So to clarify, let's say I know example.com has DKIM implemented.
I cannot receive an e-mail from example.com as I know no one that works there.
Can I still check the existence and validity of the DKIM record even though I do not know the name of the used selector? (or find the selector somehow without e-mail).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to detect if DKIM is implemented by the sender without getting a mail from the sender, extracting the selector from the DKIM-Signature header and getting the DKIM policy from DNS based on this selector.

One can check if some commonly used selectors can be found in DNS. But a successful check does not mean that any of these selector actually gets used for signing nor does it mean that the messages gets signed at all. And, no typical selector found does not mean that DKIM is not implemented.

Answer (score 4):

There are some commonly used selectors that you can try, and in fact could build your own table of possibilities to pass into a program or script to check against.

I recommend trying:

```
google
dkim
mail
default
```

For example:
`dig -t TXT +short google._domainkey.domain.com`

It should go without saying that if you have the DKIM and no email to compare it against, obviously it's not really of any use.  But if all you're interested in is identifying if it's configured, and what the public key might be, go with trying common selectors.

Comment: *"This not entirely accure, the answer by Steffen"* - I think what you write in your answer is just an extended but not actually contradicting version of what I already said with *"One can check if some commonly used selectors can be found in DNS."*. Note though that I also said *"But a successful check does not mean that any of these selector actually gets used for signing"* - a point which you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [registry.prove.email](https://registry.prove.email) to get the DKIM selectors for any domain that's been contributed to the registry prior, which includes 7,000+ DKIM keys. Selectors can be extremely diverse -- I think there are a few thousand different ones on this site, but most of the other sites I've seen just try a handful of default values. You can also manually try hitting all the selectors via DNS from a big list of selectors, such as [this one on GitHub](https://github.com/vavkamil/dkimsc4n/blob/master/dkim_selectors.lst), or you can also get a big list of selectors via the [registry.prove.email API](https://registry.prove.email/api-explorer).

Comment: So, a database so small that it's statistically improbable that a domain would be on it? I'm not sure that this is at all helpful.

Comment: Hoping that even though it may not be perfect, it can help the author with the most popular domains, and to get a sense of what common keys or selectors might be easily. Given that it's only about a month old, hopefully we see it expand!

Comment: Oh? How does one see the selectors? That's not evident anywhere. And is this your project?

Comment: You can type in any domain i.e. venmo.com, and click enter. Then you'll see boxes pop up for each selector, and rows that start with "domain:", then "selector:" etc. Where was it confusing for you? This is my friends project.

Comment: Well, for one, I would have to know one of the few domains to be able to search. And two, one cannot find out what the "common selectors are easily" because you have to collate the info across multiple (successful) queries. So, I'm repeating my comment that this is not at all helpful, and it;'s really looking like an ad to promote a particular project.

Comment: Well if your domain isn't there, you can also hit the API to get all the selectors, then run your domain through all of them via standard DNS and see if anything matches. The point is that there's no larger selector database that I've seen on the internet, so I thought it might be helpful for the poster. I'm happy to edit the answer to include this point? I'm not really interested in advertising.

Comment: https://easydmarc.com/tools/dkim-lookup Not only do they have their own database, but they have a brute-force discovery tool. They successfully found my company's selectors (and we're tiny) and all the other domains I tried on the prove.email tool that weren't there. So, perhaps you could re-focus your answer to state that there are sector databases out there that allow for look-up of known selectors. prove.email is one. easydmarc is another, and any other database you are aware of that would be relevant

Comment: I also found this dictionary of dkim selectors: https://github.com/vavkamil/dkimsc4n/blob/master/dkim_selectors.lst used by a tool to brute-force the discovery, which is a whole other approach to this question.

Comment: I'm under the impression that easy dmarc only has a database of max 30 selectors, if that -- in practice I've only seen 5. For instance, LinkedIn.com has way more matches on registry.prove.email than on easy dmarc, so I don't really trust that site to be better than your March 20 answer above. That GitHub list is a great find though, I'll update the answer!

Comment: The question isn't to enumerate all selectors, but to validate DKIM using a selector. So, one is enough. So, even with a limited range of selectors, EasyDMARC is far superior to this brand-new project... or even, as I suggested, using a brute-force approach in general.

Comment: That's a good point! I can ask the registry.prove.email devs to brute force a thousands of selectors when a new domain gets searched, and that way it can be the best of both worlds.